# Setting up Kibana-multitenancy with safeguard and openshift?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I spent a week trying to set up Safe-guard and Openshift in docker-container and completely torn apart...

I am working at a project where I plan to have clients, who can be given access to only those indices. X-pack, Safe-guard enterprise work perfectly - unfortunately until I get any clients I cannot pay yearly fees of several thousands $.

I tried to setup [Safe-guard](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard), turn off enterprise mode and then install [openshift-elasticsearch-plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/openshift-elasticsearch-plugin)

If I install them both after many tunings - I got an error that you cannot enable functionality in openshift that already enabled by safeguard.

### When I install only openshift-elasticsearch-plugin and set all settings - it says "Failed authentication for null".

Here is the repository https://github.com/SvitlanaShepitsena/Lana 
I have a small issue (somehow sleep does not work) so in order to start the cluster you need:

1. `docker-compose up`
2. `docker ps`
3. `docker exec [container-id] -it /bin/bash`
4. `./sgadmin.sh`

After 1 week of work I am desperate and beg for help :-).

Answer (score 1):

The openshift-elasticsearch-plugin is designed to add specific features to the openshift logging stack.  It, among other things, provides dynamic ACLs for users based on their openshift permissions.  I would suggest containerizing an Elasticsearch image and adding the Searchguard plugins directly.  Alternatively, versions of Elasticsearch later then the the one the plugin is designed for (2.4.4) are able to utilize XPACK that provides similar security.

Its preinstalled https://hub.docker.com/r/elastic/elasticsearch and can be configured as described https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Comment: Thank you @JeffCantrill. I probably need a license to use X-Pack - I contacted them - 14K/year. At this moment is beyond my budget.     I also installed Safeguard, but their Enterprise license is 2.5k.... I know that you need to pay to people for their work - I am ok with it, just do not have clients at this moment to share. I switched to Plan B, creating a separate elastic cluster (in Docker) for a client. I need to allocate 2 GB for each, but I did not find a better free solution. If you have any suggestion - I would appreciate if you can share with me :-)